# JavaScript's onmouseover and onmouseout events causing blinking

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have problem with JavaScript, `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events. When mouse comes to bottom edge of desired element, mouseover and mouseout effects start blinking. Here is example:

```
function menuHover(field)
{
     var img = field.nextElementSibling;
     var height = img.height;
     var bottom = 0 - Math.floor(height / 2);
     bottom += 'px';
     img.style.display = 'block';
     img.style.bottom = bottom;
}

function menuHoverOut(field)
{
    var img = field.nextElementSibling;
    img.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/index23/ety2z0zu/9/

Is there solution for this?

Comment: this issue seems to be already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464370/jquery-mouseover-and-mouseout-keeps-flashing

Comment: Thanks. But same problem with onmouseenter and onmouseleave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS would be the recommendation. But here is the answer for your question https://jsfiddle.net/ety2z0zu/11/. Please remove `img.style.bottom = bottom;` from your JavaScript

```js
function menuHover(field) {
  var img = field.nextElementSibling;
  var height = img.height;
  var bottom = 0 - Math.floor(height / 2);
  bottom += 'px';
  img.style.display = 'block';
  // console.log(height);
}

function menuHoverOut(field) {
  var img = field.nextElementSibling;
  img.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
a,
a:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  background-color: #2a4b8b;
}
header nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 23px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(2, 3, 2, .39);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(2, 3, 2, .39);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(2, 3, 2, .39);
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6173ad;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.hover-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class='main-nav'>
      <li>
        <a href='#' onmouseover='menuHover(this);' onmouseout='menuHoverOut(this);'>LINK</a>
        <img alt='' class='hover-img' src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32550463/menu-hover.png' />
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' onmouseover='menuHover(this);' onmouseout='menuHoverOut(this);'>LINK</a>
        <img alt='' class='hover-img' src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32550463/menu-hover.png' />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Refreshing that you found the actual code problem, rather than "why not use css?" (however valid that question may be)

Comment: Yes, I Agree. CSS would be the better option. But it's up to the user to decide.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I don't use CSS because i want hover effect on a tag (not li tag). And I need to display image at bottom and over all other elements (a and li). Other problem is that image is not same size for different size of menus, so I need to scale and position hover image for every menu item separately. I think that it is not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your code to use css possibilities of mouse tracking.

1. For mouse - use style `:hover`
2. To show image under element - use css directive `content` with `after`

Look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fLMSd/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use css?

By using the :hover pseudo class on the parent LI element, you can control the visibility of the image, like so:

```
.main-nav li img.hover-img {
    display: none;
}

.main-nav li:hover img.hover-img {
    display: inline;
}
```

See it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/vugjp340/1/

And maybe it would be nicer with an opacity transition.

Comment: Thanks for answers. LI elements is too big for hover effect. I have to use hover effect on A element. I don't use CSS because i want hover effect on a tag (not li tag). And I need to display image at bottom and over all other elements (a and li). Other problem is that image is not same size for different size of menus, so I need to scale and position hover image for every menu item separately. I think that it is not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing that effect in javascript and not just with css?

Three little changes here:
1. remove `padding-top` from `.main-nav li`
2. add `padding-top` from `.main-nav li a`
3. add:

```
.main-nav li:hover img.hover-img {
    display:block;
}
```

Now everything is almost the same except you can click on the "entire" button which has now more height like it is visible. https://jsfiddle.net/ety2z0zu/16/

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found out what is a problem. Problem could be in image that appears on mouse over. When image appear it come over a tag, and browser fire mouse out events, then image hide and browser fire mouse over event and so on in the loop.

Thank you all for helping.